# How do I add an attribute to an instance variable in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, instance-variables

Using Rails 4, in a controller I would like to add an attribute to an instance variable.

Sorry for the poor example, I'm trying to keep it simple.

E.g. In a controller, I create a new instance variable by looking up some users named John. Now, in my controller, I would like to sum up all the ages for all Users named John, put that summed age back in to the instance variable so it is available to the view.

The User model has attributes 'id', 'name' and 'age'.

```
@foo_users = Users.where(name: 'John')

@foo_users.each do |foo|
  @foo_users.age_sum = Users.where(name: 'John').sum(:age)  <-- this does not work
end
```

I have no need to save that summed age back to a database, since I will only use it in one view. I would like to be able to display all the users:

```
<% @foo_users.each do |user| %>
  User name: <%= user.name =>
  Sum of ages: <%= user.age_sum %>
<% end %>
```

**Update: I might have over simplified my example. Here is a closer to reality example.**

A company owns hotels. Hotels have Rooms. Management software delivers to the company daily Hotel_Statistics via an API. For lack of a better word, these Hotel_Statistics contain the hotel_id, daily check-ins, daily check-outs. In the company's back-office Rails app that I am working on, on the page displayed there is a table of hotels with their given most recent statistics. One line would look like:

```
Hotel Id: 123
Daily check-ins: 50 
Daily check-outs: 48

Hotel Id: 124
Daily check-ins: 35
Daily check-outs: 37
```

The company wants to also display the running sum of the last 30 days of check-ins (outs, net check-ins). 
To accomplish this, in my controller, I find the Hotel_Statics for the most recent date (normally yesterday).

```
latest_stat = HotelStatistic.order('date DESC, hotel_id DESC').first
@latest_date = latest_stat.date
@recent_stats = HotelStatistic.where(date: @latest_date).order('hotel.id ASC').all
```

I display the details of @recent_stats in my view.

Now, I would like to display in my view the sum of the last 30 days of @recent_stats.check_ins for each Hotel. My idea was to sum up the the last 30 days of check_ins statistics for a given Hotel like:

```
@recent_stats.each do |stat|
    @last_30_days_check_ins = HotelStatistic.where(hotel_id: stat.hotel_id).where("date >= ?", Date.today - 30).sum(:check_ins)
end
```

The math works, but I need a way to access the 30 day sum variable for each hotel. I was a hoping to make this easy in the view by adding the hotel 30 day sum to the @recent_stats instance variable so in my view I could do:

```
<% @recent_stats.each do |statistic| %>
    Hotel Id: <%= statistic.hotel_id %>
    Daily check-ins: <%= statistic.check_ins %>
    Last 30 days check-ins: <%= statistic.last_30_days_check_ins %>     
<% end %>
```

Does this more realistic example change anything in your suggested answers? Thanks

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm obviously confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `@foo_users` is `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Trying to add `age_sum` as a new attribute to an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object doesn't make sense because semantically `age_sum` is not an attribute of `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects. It's better to store the sum of ages in a new instance variable, for example `@user_age_sum`.

**UPDATE**
Try the following

```
class HotelStatistic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hotel
end

class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hotel_statistics

  def last_30_days_check_ins
    self.hotel_statistics.where("date >= ?", 30.days.ago).sum(:check_ins)
  end

end
```

Keep the existing code for building `@recent_stats` in the controller

In the view

```
<% @recent_stats.each do |statistic| %>
    Hotel Id: <%= statistic.hotel_id %>
    Daily check-ins: <%= statistic.check_ins %>
    Last 30 days check-ins: <%= statistic.hotel.last_30_days_check_ins %>     
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid of. In my .each do loop can I create a new variable for each |user|. For instance @{user.name}.age_sum?

Comment: While it's possible to add a new attribute to the User model called `age_sum`, I recommend against that because semantically `age_sum` is not an attribute of User objects. From the object oriented programming perspective, the basic idea is an attribute should be stored in the right object not any objects that are available to you (in your case, `ActiveRecord::Relation` and then `User`.

Comment: Considering that I will only ever use the last_30_days_check_ins on one single view (out of ~20 that use the Hotel variable), isn't adding this code to the model overkill? Won't this code be run when any page uses the Hotel model?

Comment: `last_30_days_check_ins` is a method in the Hotel class, it is only executed when you call it on a Hotel object.

Comment: Please check out this article http://bit.ly/1vt8i5m, it explains why the calculation of the last 30 days' check-ins should be in a separate method instead of being in a method in the controller.

Comment: Thank you. This works great. I obviously need to read up more on MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Using `select` should solve your problem:

```
@users = User.select("*, SUM(age) as age_sum").where(name: 'John')
```

Now each `User` in the `@users` array will have a `age_sum` property. This is not 100% ideal as the value of the property will be the same on each instance, but it will work with how you've setup your view.

**Edit**
It's possible to dynamically define a method on an instance manually:

```
@foo_users.each do |foo|
  def foo.age_sum; Users.where(name: 'John').sum(:age); end;
end
```

However while this is possible, it would have to be a very good use case to justify the negative impact this may have (such as on how readable, efficient and maintainable the code is). There are probably much better OO ways to solve the same problem

Comment: Thanks, that gets the right result, but doesn't answer the question. The question is how to inject a new attribute in to an already established instance variable.

Comment: For a more realistic use case, see my edit to the original question. Thanks.